# Compiling C++ OpenCV code to Javascript with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, webassembly

I have C++ that includes header files from OpenCV.  I am trying to convert this to WebAssembly with Emscripten.  When I try to compile using:

```sh
em++ main.cpp -s WASM=1 -o seamCarve.html
```

I get the following error message:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
shared:ERROR: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

This is my first time working with WebAssembler so I am not really sure what to do.  I have compiled the OpenCV library to create an opencv.js as outlined by the steps on the following link:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

I am not sure if I need to include this js file in my compilation or if I need to include each of the header files when I compile.

Comment: So you mean you got opencv.js and its .wasm files as well?

Comment: @BumsikKim I compiled the opencv.js file without really knowing for sure if I needed it.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like it is used for calling OpenCV functions in javascript rather than for compiling C++ code that includes OpenCV functions to javascript. I do not have any .wasm files.

Answer (score 3):

In general when using libraries with your C/C++ code you'll have to link it when producing the executable binary.

So when using emscripten you'll first have to compile the library, and then you can use e.g. the static library file `mylib.a` when linking so that your `emcc` command will look something like this:

`em++ -s WASM=1  main.cpp libopencv.a -o seamCarve.html`

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also describe how to compile a library like opencv, how to get to the libopencv.a?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV.js is meant to be included in your HTML document similar to any JavaScript code. You can then access almost all OpenCV functions from your JavaScript code.

Now you can build your OpenCV for WebAssembly. The good part about that, you do not need to change your JavaScript code because WASM module is included in OpenCV.js file, but you need to compile for WASM(WebAssembly)

take a look at this link
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

Comment: thank you for your explantion . after I get wasm format of opencv , how can I compile my own c++ code ( which contains opencv ) to wasm file . would you please guide me for the command I must use ?

Comment: The way I do it after getting OpenCV wasm version, is to access it from JavaScript. Everything you need to do with C++ version is available in JavaScript (not really everything but for the most parts) . Note, Even though you use JavaScript, wasm is the one that is doing image processing.

Comment: i've tried that , but c++ wasm version of code is about 2 times faster than javascript wasm . that is the main reason of using cpp instead of js